# SELECT values from database based on CASEs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table Tb1 with n columns and m count of rows.

```
Tb1
========================================
field_0... field_k... field_p... field_n
```

Here is the pseudo-code that I need to express in SQL

```
if(count(select distinct Tb1.field_k) > 1) return "string_literal"
else return Tb1.field_p
```

The result set should have m count of rows.

Comment: **WHAT** database - which version ???

Comment: Please express in English what you want the query to do. it is not clear from your question, or from your psudeo code

Comment: @marc_s: The database vendor is MS SQL Server, but I was looking for the most plain SQL.

Comment: @Charles Bretana: in other words: if I have different values in Tb1.field_k, I need to get m count of "string_literal, if all the values in Tb1.field_k are the same, I need to get Tb1.field_p column. Hope it is clear now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN x.testcase > 1 THEN "string_literal"
        ELSE Tb1.field_p
    END AS SomeCol
FROM
   Tb1
   CROSS JOIN
   (
   SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT Tb1.field_k) AS testcase
   FROM Tb1
   ) x
```

Notes:

- Tb1.field_p must be a compatible datatype to "string_literal"